# combine analysis and artificial intelligence

Tags: analysis, artificial-intelligence

I'm sorry if I ask this question at the wrong place,
but I don't know a better one.
I am a Master's student and I am really interested in analysis, but I also
want to get into AI.
Does anyone know a natural way to combine these two interests?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of analysis are you referring to, it is wide topic.

Comment: Mostly real analysis, but I haven't specialised yet. That's one of the reasons I'm asking because if someone knows a cool connection between analysis and AI I would think about specialising in that area.

Comment: as i can imagine, for some AI used for object recognition, fourier analysis might be useful to reduce information or extract feature information.

Comment: Have you considered machine learning? It also has the advantage of good post-graduation job prospects.

Comment: Yes, i did but only superficially yet. It looks very interesting. Do you know which kinds of analysis courses would be helpful for that?